# How do I attach keypress event to var inputElement = $(this).parent().find("input[myAttributeID]");?

Tags: jquery

I need to attach keypress event to a result of selector:

```
var inputElement = $(this).parent().find("input[myAttributeID]");
```

I know how to attach as a function by do it from a element in a var I don't even know how to call it

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
inputElement.on("keypress", function(oEvent) { });
//or
var inputElement = $(this).parent()
                          .find("input[myAttributeID]")
                          .on
                          (
                              "keypress", 
                              function(oEvent) 
                              {
                                  if (oEvent.keyCode == 13)
                                  { /* whatever happens */ }  
                              }
                          );
```

and when the keypress event occurs, your function will be called. 
To call it from your code to test :

```
inputElement.trigger("keypress");
```

Comment: thanks, trying to figure out how I get the keyCode in order to get the 13

Comment: if ((oEvent.keyCode ? oEvent.keyCode : e.which) == 13) { /* Enter key code here */ } Please mark as answer if this suits your requirements for your original question. :)

Comment: jQuery normalizes `e.which`, there is no reason to test for the existence of `keyCode` in `event`.